# navigateToURL failed open up browser on iPad (Adobe Air)

Tags: air, actionscript-3

Quick question, I am using Adobe AIR to develop an app under iPad. Why `navigateToURL` not open up the Safari under iPad? it works under Android.

```
if(e == 'pdf')
{
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e)
    {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
        var url:String = 'http://files.au2.schneider-electric.com/locator/index.php?controller=pdfGenerator&action=fetchroom&roomid=' + variables.roomid + '&userid=0';
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

        try
        {
            navigateToURL(request, '_blank'); // second argument is target
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            trace("Error occurred!");
        }
    });
}
```

Just wondering is it Adobe Air can't open browsers on Mobiles Devices at all?

Comment: loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

Comment: Thanks for the Help Marty, but my problem is it don't open the Safari, and it just sits there doing nothing. on the pc it would open the browser straight way.

Comment: Any idea why it won't open up the browser with navigateToURL? cause it certainly work under desktop and android platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can expect that PDFs load like regular webpages on iOS.  This is untested, but the idea is to create a `StageWebView` instance, using it to load the PDF:

```
var swv:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0,wid,ht);
swv.stage = stage;
swv.loadURL( someUrl );
```

EDIT:

See the [Adobe docs on StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) as well.